# Add class to img in json that linked to html

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, xml

```
name: "Control",
                icon: `/images/icon/process.png`,
                class: "inverted",
                color: "#ed3467",
                blocks: [{
                        xml: `
                                <block type="controls_wait">
                                    <value name="time">
                                        <shadow type="math_number">
                                            <field name="NUM">1</field>
                                        </shadow>
                                    </value>
                                </block>
                            `
                    }
```

i want to add class like the class in html in the json the class will be class="inverted"
i can change it in html inspect and it work but idk how to do it here
and sorry i am beginner

`<img src="/./images/icon/led.png" alt="" class="inverted">`
this is how i want to be in html but from the inspect i add the class

Comment: Please post the consumer  of the above object.

Comment: This json in separate file from html and css

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.